# How to Test Cookbook in CHEF using DOCKER

Tags: docker, chef-infra, cookbook, inspec

I am trying to test a simple cookbook recipe using docker driver. But, I get an error.

Can someone please help? I really gave my all effort trying several things but none of them worked. I had installed docker kitchen driver also using command: `chef gem install kitchen-docker`. Below are my configurational files, chef versions, kitchen.yml file etc.

**Chef version**

```
Chef Workstation version: 22.6.973
Chef InSpec version: 4.56.20
Chef CLI version: 5.6.1
Chef Habitat version: 1.6.420
Test Kitchen version: 3.2.2
Cookstyle version: 7.32.1
Chef Infra Client version: 17.10.0
```

---

`chef gem list kitchen-docker` gives output as: `kitchen-docker (2.13.0)`

**Below is my `kitchen.yml` file**

```yaml
---
driver:
  name: docker
  provision_command: curl -L https://www.chef.io/chef/install.sh | bash

provisioner:
  name: chef_zero

  ## product_name and product_version specifies a specific Chef product and version to install.
  ## see the Chef documentation for more details: https://docs.chef.io/workstation/config_yml_kitchen/
  #  product_name: chef
  #  product_version: 17

verifier:
  name: inspec

platforms:
  - name: ubuntu
  - name: centos-7
    driver_config:
      image: 'centos:7'
      platform: centos

transport:
  name: docker

suites:
  - name: default
    run_list:
       - recipe[docker-cookbook::default]
    verifier:
      inspec_tests:
        - test/integration/default
    attributes:
```

---

**My recipe: `default.rb`**

```rb
#
# Cookbook:: docker-cookbook
# Recipe:: default
#
# Copyright:: 2022, The Authors, All Rights Reserved.

file '/tmp/test.txt' do
  content 'This is managed by Rapidops'
  action :create
end
```

But, when I do `kitchen list`, I am getting below error:

```
>>>>>> ------Exception-------
>>>>>> Class: Kitchen::UserError
>>>>>> Message: Kitchen YAML file /root/chef-repo/cookbooks/docker-cookbook/recipes/kitchen.yml does not exist.
>>>>>> ----------------------
>>>>>> Please see .kitchen/logs/kitchen.log for more details
>>>>>> Also try running `kitchen diagnose --all` for configuration
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: The message states it very clearly: "Message: Kitchen YAML file /root/chef-repo/cookbooks/docker-cookbook/recipes/kitchen.yml does not exist.". Where is your kitchen.yml?

Answer (score 0):

As per error message, you are trying to run `kitchen` commands from recipe directory -
`/root/chef-repo/cookbooks/docker-cookbook/recipes/kitchen.yml does not exist`
You should run kitchen commands from root level of cookbook.
In you case, it is - `/root/chef-repo/cookbooks/docker-cookbook`